# Salesforce Login via Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, salesforce

I am loging into salesforce account and thus getting this issue while running of selenium script.

"Your login attempt has failed. The username or password may be incorrect, or your location or login time may be restricted. Please contact the administrator at your company for help".

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to include your security token in your credentials:  https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000glADAAY

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is occurring as it is not able to identify your IP  as your Ip outside Iprange specified by your Salesforce admin. You may request your Salesforce Admin to add your IP to trusted IP range. It not only solve your problem but also bypass the verification